# get if streamer is on Stream

Tags: javascript, discord.js, twitch, twitch-api

I'm making a Twitch and Discord bot, but now I have a problem.

I want to check if the streamer is live and send a console.log() if it is live, but I am not able to do that.

```
require("dotenv").config();
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { MessageAttachment } = require('discord.js');
const Canvas = require('canvas');
const { createCanvas, loadImage } = require('canvas');
const fs = require('fs');
const customCommandsFile = 'commands/custom_commands.json';
let customCommands = {};
const intents = ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MEMBERS", "GUILD_MESSAGES"];
const client = new Discord.Client({intents: intents, ws:{intents: intents}});
const { StaticAuthProvider } = require('twitch-auth');
const TwitchAPI = require('twitch');
const tmi = require('tmi.js');
const twitchClient = new tmi.Client({
  options: {
    debug: true
  },
  identity: {
    username: process.env.USERNAME,
    password: process.env.PASSWORD
  },
  channels: [ '#errxino' ]
});
const clientId = process.env.TWITCH_CLIENT_ID;
const accessToken = process.env.TWITCH_ACCESS_TOKEN;

const authProvider = new StaticAuthProvider(clientId, accessToken, ['channel:manage:broadcast', 'user:edit:broadcast', 'channel:moderate', 'chat:edit', 'chat:read']);
const twitch = new TwitchAPI({ authProvider });


// FUNCTIONS
function createCustomCommand(command, response) {
  // Agrega el comando personalizado al objeto customCommands
  customCommands[command] = response;

  // Escribe el objeto customCommands en un archivo JSON
  fs.writeFile('commands/custom_commands.json', JSON.stringify(customCommands), err => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return;
    }
    const channel = client.channels.cache.find(c => c.name === "log-twitchbot");
    if (!channel) {
      console.error(`No se encontró el canal de Discord con el nombre "log-twitchbot".`);
      return;
    }

    // Actualiza los comandos personalizados en twitchClient
    twitchClient.removeAllListeners('message');
    twitchClient.on('message', async (channel, tags, message, self) => {
      if (self) return;

      if (message.startsWith('!')) {
        const args = message.slice(1).split(' ');
        const command = args[0];

        // Verifica si el comando personalizado existe y lo ejecuta si lo hace
        if (customCommands[command]) {
          twitchClient.say(channel, customCommands[command]);
        }
      }
    });
  });
}

function clearCustomCommands() {
  customCommands = {};
  fs.writeFileSync('commands/custom_commands.json', JSON.stringify(customCommands));
}

fs.readFile(customCommandsFile, (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }
  customCommands = JSON.parse(data);
});


// TWITCH BOT
twitchClient.connect();

twitchClient.on('connected', (address, port) => {
  // Busca el canal de Discord por su nombre
  const channel = client.channels.cache.find(c => c.name === "log-twitchbot");
  if (!channel) {
    console.error(`No se encontró el canal de Discord con el nombre "log-twitchbot".`);
    return;
  }

  // Envía un mensaje de inicio de sesión a un canal de Discord
  const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#00FF09')
    .setAuthor({ name: 'ErrXino.tv', iconURL: 'https://i.imgur.com/gTmSG8Z.png' })
    .setFields(
      { name: 'Twitch bot:', value: 'equis_bot'},
      { name: 'Estado:', value: 'Iniciado✅'},
    )
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter({ text: 'ErrXino.tv', iconURL: 'https://i.imgur.com/gTmSG8Z.png' });
  channel.send({ embeds: [embed] })
  return;
});

twitchClient.on('message', async (channel, tags, message, self) => {
  if (self) return;

  const args = message.slice(0).split(' ');
  const command = args[0].toLowerCase(); // convertimos el comando a minúsculas
  if (args[0].startsWith('!')){
    console.log(command)
    if (customCommands[command]) { // comprobamos si el comando existe
      twitchClient.say(channel, customCommands[command]); // enviamos el contenido del comando
    }
  }
});

// DISCORD BOT
client.on('ready', () => {
  // Busca el canal de Discord por su nombre y se une a él
  const channel = client.channels.cache.find(c => c.name === "log-twitchbot");
  if (!channel) {
    console.error(`No se encontró el canal de Discord con el nombre "log-twitchbot".`);
    return;
  }
  
  const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#00FF09')
    .setAuthor({ name: 'ErrXino.tv', iconURL: 'https://i.imgur.com/gTmSG8Z.png' })
    .setFields(
      { name: 'Discord bot:', value: `${client.user.tag}`},
      { name: 'Estado:', value: 'Iniciado✅'},
    )
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter({ text: 'ErrXino.tv', iconURL: 'https://i.imgur.com/gTmSG8Z.png' });
  channel.send({ embeds: [embed] })
  client.user.setActivity("canal de ErrXino", {
    type: "STREAMING",
    url: "https://www.twitch.tv/errxino"
  });
  return;
});

client.login(process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN);
```

I have tried with 'getStreamByUser', or with 'channel', but neither work. I was using 'const TwitchAPI = require('twitch-api-v5');' to make the API call.

Comment: What do you  mean `getStreamByUser` didn't work? What results are you getting? That function is usually how you check if they are online.

Comment: @Slight Didn't get any reply

Comment: Do you get a reply if you check against a streamer that you know is currently streaming?

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if I don't read over every line of your code, but generally this is how I would check if a streamer is online/offline using twitch's js library.

```js
const TwitchAPI = require('twitch-api');
const twitch = new TwitchAPI({
    clientId: 'your_client_id_here',
    clientSecret: 'your_client_secret_here'
});

async function isStreamerLive(streamerName) {
    const streamData = await twitch.getStreamByUser(streamerName);
    return streamData !== null;
}
```

Try this code and, if it works, work backwards with your code to see what's wrong.

Comment: I've tried but it won't let me.

Comment: Sorry, it's `getStreamByUser`, not UserName. Fixed my code.